# NoSuchElementException: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters

Tags: appium, hybrid-mobile-app, appium-ios

Code i am using:

```
public class SafariTest {
private static IOSDriver iOSDriver;
private WebElement loginSettingsButton;
@Before
public void preTest() throws MalformedURLException {
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "xxxx");
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "iOS");
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "12.1");

    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, "XCUITest");
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.UDID, "xxxx");
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP,"/xxx.app");

    iOSDriver = new IOSDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);

    //webDriver = new AppiumDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
}
@Test
public void testCase(){
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(iOSDriver, 15); 
loginSettingsButton = iOSDriver.findElement(By.name("loginSettingsButton"));
loginSettingsButton.click();
}

@After
public void finishTest(){
    //  webDriver.quit();
}

public static void setContextToWebview(){
    Set<String> availableContexts = iOSDriver.getContextHandles();
    availableContexts.stream()
            .filter(context -> context.toLowerCase().contains("webview"))
            .forEach(newcontext -> iOSDriver.context(newcontext));
}

}
```

The error which i got:

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.
>   For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
>   Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
>   System info: host: 'xxxx.local', ip: 'xxxxx', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.14.4', java.version: '1.8.0_152-release'
>   Driver info: io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver
>   Capabilities {app: xxx, automationName: XCUITest, browserName: , databaseEnabled: false, deviceName: xxxx, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: false, networkConnectionEnabled: false, platform: MAC, platformName: iOS, platformVersion: 12.1, takesScreenshot: true, udid: xxxx..., webStorageEnabled: false}
>   Session ID: a2b7627f-9792-4df3-874b-96ced13fc185
>   *** Element info: {Using=name, value=loginSettingsButton}
>   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
>       at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:239)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
>       at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:42)
>       at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
>       at io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver.execute(IOSDriver.java:1)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:323)
>       at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.findElement(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:62)
>       at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.findElement(AppiumDriver.java:1)
>       at io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver.findElement(IOSDriver.java:1)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByName(RemoteWebDriver.java:404)
>       at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.findElementByName(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:118)
>       at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.findElementByName(AppiumDriver.java:1)
>       at io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver.findElementByName(IOSDriver.java:1)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByName.findElement(By.java:284)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:315)
>       at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.findElement(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:58)
>       at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.findElement(AppiumDriver.java:1)
>       at io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver.findElement(IOSDriver.java:1)
>       at com.example.appiumapplication.SafariTest.testCase(SafariTest.java:63)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
>       at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
>       at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
>   Process finished with exit code 255

Comment: Can you please clarify on what line of code you get this error? I am assuming it is `loginSettingsButton = iOSDriver.findElement(By.name("loginSettingsButton"));` right? Assumptions are never a good starting point answering a question. Continuing on my assumption, did you check if a element with given name was present in `IOSDriver.PageSource`?

Comment: yes i am getting error on loginSettingsButton = iOSDriver.findElement(By.name("loginSettingsButton")); this line.

Comment: I have checked in pagesource and i am getting button static text as name, not name given in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using **findElement(By.Name("..."))** method please try to use **findElementByAccessibilityId("loginSettingsButton")**

```
loginSettingsButton = iOSDriver.findElementByAccessibiltyId("loginSettingsButton");
```

> make sure you have element present with **loginSettingsButton** as **automationId** i.e content description
>
> Using name, xpath is not recommended for appium.You must use accessibilty id or id while using appium. If you don't have automation id like cont-desc, resource-id or id, you can ask your developer team to add it

Comment: I have tried with AccessibilityId but i am getting same error. And i have confirmed with my development team that they had added name and id as automation id in code. So is there any other thing we need to add in our code for automation id?

Comment: can you confirm if automation id is present in the screen using **Appium Desktop Inspector**?

Comment: Also check the pageSource property from your driver. Is the devs added name and automationId, you should at least see those property values in the [pageSource](https://appium.io/docs/en/commands/session/source/) xml.

Comment: Actually in code we have passes id and name but in pagesource i am not getting that. In pagesource i am getting the static text of button as "Name".

Comment: Did you tried using appium desktop inspector? It will show you **xpath** and **id**, **accessibilityID** if there are any. You can use xpath shown in appium desktop inspector if there is no any unique id

Comment: But XPATH is not a recommended way as per my knowledge.

Comment: yes xpath is not recommened way. Also findElementByName is also not recommended way. The recommended way is to use **accessibilityId**  and **id**